Degrees of Freedom with Overlapping Moving Averages in Time Series Analysis
I'm trying to understand how to quantify the degrees of freedom used by a moving average crossover system in a time series— since a more complex model consumes more degrees of freedom and can lead to overfitting. I came across this discussion on degrees of freedom, but I'm unsure how to apply it to overlapping data in time series analysis.
I'm studying the application of moving averages where average crossover system where signals are generated when a shorter-term moving average crosses above or below a longer-term moving average of the same data series.
Degrees of freedom cases
How many degrees of freedom are consumed in each of the following cases of moving average crossover system that is applied to a time series of stock data with varying parameters?

SMA(10, low) and SMA(20, low)
SMA(10, low) and SMA(20, high)
SMA(10, low) and EMA(20, low)
SMA(10, low) and EMA(20, high)

Each case above first shows the short-term then the long-term moving average parameters.
Abbreviations: SMA = Simple Moving Average, EMA = Exponential Moving Average Low/High = The lowest/highest price at which a stock traded during a specific time period
Questions Considerations:

Degrees of Freedom Consumption: How many degrees of freedom are consumed in each case? Should overlapping data points (due to moving averages on the same or different price types) be considered when calculating degrees of freedom?

Impact of Data Overlap: Does calculating multiple moving averages on the same underlying data (e.g., low prices) consume more degrees of freedom than using different data points (e.g., low and high prices)?

Different Moving Averages: How does using different types of moving averages (SMA vs. EMA) affect the degrees of freedom?


Any insights or references on calculating degrees of freedom in this context would be greatly appreciated!
